# Square inside a square area exam question

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

[image]

I need to work out the area of the shaded section.

I think that the area of the right angle triangle in the sqare is $10 * 5 / 2 = 25cm^2$

But I don't know how to use that to work out the area of the shaded section.

Comment: This is not an exam question: https://twitter.com/Cshearer41/status/1130478770861871104

Comment: Oh sorry i don't know my teacher said it was an exam question.

Comment: Hint: All the right triangles are similar.